# fatal error: 'third_party/blink/renderer/platform/wtf/std_lib_extras.h' File not found: Building Chromium from source

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chromium

I am trying to build Chromium from source. I am on Macbook Pro 2018. I am following instructions from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/mac_build_instructions.md). When I am running command for autoninza, I am getting the error that:

```
../../third_party/blink/renderer/platform/shared_buffer.h:38:10: fatal error: 'third_party/blink/renderer/platform/wtf/std_lib_extras.h' file not found
#include "third_party/blink/renderer/platform/wtf/std_lib_extras.h"
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[16/8459] CXX obj/third_party/blink/renderer/bindings/core/v8/bindings_core_impl/input_event_init.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The file `std_lib_extras.h` actually exists at the right path. I have cleaned the entire directory and repeated the process again but this does not work. What should I do?

PS: I am building chromium as I need to generate stacktrace for one of my project bug that throws Aw Snap. Earlier, I tried using Chrome Canary for that following the instructions from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/877352/debug-aw-snap-error-in-chrome)